# Magento 2 - Changing the PayPal logo on the Checkout page

Tags: magento2.2, paypal

I am trying to change the PayPal logo that appears on the checkout page, just before the customer is forwarded to PayPal to make a payment. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I looked everywhere and tried to change the file below:

./vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/templates/payment/mark.phtml

Still no joy. Any help or guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Please change in below file**

```
/vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express-in-context.html
```

**After change below file please run below**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Not a good idea to edit core files, extend it in your theme instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file in the path:

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_folder]/[theme_folder]/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment
```

The file

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" css="_active: getCode() == isChecked()" afterRender="initListeners">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio testing"
               attr="id: getCode()"
               ko-value="getCode()"
               ko-checked="isChecked"
               click="selectPaymentMethod"
               visible="isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label attr="for: getCode()" class="label">
            <!-- PayPal Logo-->
            <!-- Here to change log-->
            <img attr="src: getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc(), alt: $t('Acceptance Mark')" class="payment-icon"/>
            <!-- PayPal Logo -->
            <span text="getTitle()"/>
            <a class="action action-help"
               attr="href: getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()"
               click="showAcceptanceWindow"
               translate="'What is PayPal?'"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <each args="getRegion('messages')" render=""/>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <each args="$parent.getRegion('before-place-order')" render=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar" attr="id: getButtonId()" afterRender="renderPayPalButtons"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to locate where the image is coming from. Location:

```
vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express-in-context.html
```

Create this file in your theme to over-ride core Magento functionality:

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_folder]/[theme_folder]/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express-in-context.html
```

On (or around about) line 19, replace the img src with the src of the new image. Since this is a html file (not a phtml file), you won't be able to use php within this file so any reference to

Flush the magento cache(s):
php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file from vendor

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express-in-context.html

to your custom theme path

> app/design/frontend/[vendor_folder]/[theme_folder]/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express-in-context.html

And finally, replace your Paypal logo from line no. 19

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" css="_active: getCode() == isChecked()" afterRender="initListeners">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               attr="id: getCode()"
               ko-value="getCode()"
               ko-checked="isChecked"
               click="selectPaymentMethod"
               visible="isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label attr="for: getCode()" class="label">
            <!-- PayPal Logo -->
            <img attr="src: getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc(), alt: $t('Acceptance Mark')" class="payment-icon"/>
            <!-- PayPal Logo -->
            <span text="getTitle()"/>
            <a class="action action-help"
               attr="href: getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()"
               click="showAcceptanceWindow"
               translate="'What is PayPal?'"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <each args="getRegion('messages')" render=""/>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <each args="$parent.getRegion('before-place-order')" render=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar" attr="id: getButtonId()" afterRender="renderPayPalButtons"/>
        <div class="payment-method-extra-content">
            <each args="$parent.getRegion('paypal-method-extra-content')" render=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```